# Default app on win 10 not working

Tags: windows-10, administrator, modern-ui

After enable build-in administrator, some of my app can not be accessed

[image]

also some pinned like weather on start menu disappear.

how to fix this.. or there's a way to reset user without reinstall windows

Comment: I try create new user all those application work.
but still.. I want to use the build-in users because all app will automatically run as administrator

Comment: This is not something new but goes back to Windows 8 days.